# Android EditText and OnEditorActionListener - memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-edittext, android-memory

I am tracking down a memory leak in my Android app and this EditText uses a lot of memory (2.8MB) and disabling it makes the leak disappear.

So can anyone spot a (potential) memoryleak in this code?
I find it a bit problematic that I never return true from the OnEditorActionListener since I replace the fragment before (or will the return still be called? I should step through the code and check that).

Also, maybe I am not closing the editor properly, just hiding it away?

```
 public void addHighscoreEdittext()
{   
    final HighscoresDatabaseHandler dbHandler = ( (MainActivity) getActivity() ).theDatabasehandler;

    HighscoreEdittext = new EditText( getActivity() );
    HighscoreEdittext.setX( ( actualScreenSizeX - actualScreenSizeX / 8 * 6 ) / 2 );
    HighscoreEdittext.setY( actualScreenSizeY / 10 * 3 );

    LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams( actualScreenSizeX / 8 * 6, actualScreenSizeY / 6 );
    HighscoreEdittext.setLayoutParams( lparams );
    HighscoreEdittext.setInputType( InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT );

    HighscoreEdittext.setBackground( getResources().getDrawable( R.layout.start_finish_button ) );

    HighscoreEdittext.setTextColor( Constants.TEXT_COLOR_ON_TRANSPARENT_BROWN );
    HighscoreEdittext.setHintTextColor( Constants.TEXT_COLOR_ON_TRANSPARENT_BROWN );
    HighscoreEdittext.setHint( "New best time! Enter name..." );

    ((ViewGroup) (getActivity()).findViewById( android.R.id.content )).addView( HighscoreEdittext );

    HighscoreEdittext.setOnEditorActionListener(
        new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction( TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event ) 
            {                   
                if ( actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE )
                {
                    SharedData.GameFinished = false;

                    String name = v.getText().toString();
                    if ( name.length() > 8 )
                    {
                        name = name.substring( 0, 8 );
                    }
                    dbHandler.updateHighscore(
                            new Highscore(
                                    SharedData.LevelPlayed, 
                                    name, 
                                    SharedData.LevelTime ) ); 

                    /* Hide keyboard */
                    HighscoreEdittext.clearFocus();
                    InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService( Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE );
                    in.hideSoftInputFromWindow( HighscoreEdittext.getApplicationWindowToken(), 
                            InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS );

                    ((ViewGroup) getActivity().findViewById( android.R.id.content )).removeView( HighscoreEdittext );

                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace( R.id.fragment_content, new ChooseLevelFragment(), "chooselevel" );
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();

                    return true;              
                }

                return false;
            }
    });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you have fragmentTransaction.commit(). This may be the issue since commit is a synchronous task and will cause the app to wait for it. See if you can use an async task for it if you do not need the data right away.